# Wrong CMake install dirs

Tags: cmake, installation

I use CMake `GNUInstallDirs` like this:

```
set(BINDIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_BINDIR}" CACHE STRING "Where install binary")
set(DATADIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_DATADIR}/cubosphere" CACHE STRING "Data location (install-time)")
set(RUNTIME_DATADIR "${DATADIR}" CACHE STRING "Data location (run-time)")
```

However, if `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` isn't specified, I get `/bin` and `/shared` as values.

Strange results also can be recieved using `message(WARNING "${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_DATADIR}")`: `/bin` on clean run, `/usr/local/bin` on cached one.

Is there a way to overcome this issue, e.g. use `/usr/local/bin` instead of `/bin`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake sets *default* value of `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` only when `project()` is called. Because the module `GNUInstallDirs` uses this variable, it should be included **after** the `project()`:

```
project(MyProject)
# ...
include(GNUInstallDirs)
```